# Calculus 2 and mass calculation.

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I'd like to calculate a mass bounded by the following surfaces:

$x^2+y^2=8z$, $x^2=2z$ and $z=2$

The mass distribution is continues and equals to $\rho(x,y,z)=1$

I'm stuck with the answer $32\pi\over6$ by solving the following integral:

$\int_{0}^{2} \int_{-\sqrt{2z}}^{\sqrt{2z}}\int_{-\sqrt{8z-x^2}}^{\sqrt{8z-x^2}}1 \,dy\,dx\,dz$

which is the mass of the bounded region and is apparently incorrect, I'd appreciate any help in solving this.

Answer (score 1):

I found my mistake, I should have used the following formula to integrate correctly, listed below:

$$\int \sqrt{a^2-z^2}dz = {z\over 2} \sqrt{a^2-z^2}+{a^2\over 2}\arcsin{z\over a}+C$$

after calculation and simplification this integral:
$$\int_{-\sqrt{2 z}}^{\sqrt{2 z}} 2 \sqrt{8 z - x^2} dx = (4 \sqrt 3 + 8 \pi/3) z$$
becomes

$$ \int_{0}^{2} (\dfrac{\left(8{\pi}+3{\cdot}2^\frac{3}{2}\sqrt{6}\right)z}{3}) dz $$

final calculation makes it up to be:

$$ 8(\sqrt{3}+\frac{2}{3}\pi)$$

which is different from my original answer.

Answer (score 0):

Integral looks ok, I think your solution is i incorrect. Try providing your answers after each integral.

After the second inner integral, you should have
$$\int_{-\sqrt{2 z}}^{\sqrt{2 z}} 2 \sqrt{8 z - x^2} dx = (4 \sqrt 3 + 8 \pi/3) z$$.

Last step you get this times 4.